# Excess tree conflicts after merge of TRUNK into branch

Tags: svn, merge, trunk, tree-conflict

I'm running into dozens of excess tree conflicts trying to merge a subversion branch back into TRUNK after that branch had TRUNK merged into it.  Here's what happened in chronological order.

1. Branch was made off of TRUNK and edits were made to A
2. Files were added into TRUNK to B
3. I merged TRUNK into my BRANCH and verified, by doing *svn log* that the files and directories,B, that were added to my branch retained their history of edits from the trunk.
4. In my branch, I changed some of the files in set B, which were merged in from TRUNK during step 3
5. I try to merge my branch into the TRUNK

During my merge, all files in B that were added to my branch during step 3 show as *Tree conflict*  The vast majority of these files were not touched by me, in any way.

A small subset of the files in B marked as *Tree conflict* have actually been changed in my branch, but as far as the svn UI (command line or GUI) these are indistinguishable from the sea of files that I have not modified.

I definitely don't want to manually examine hundreds of files looking for the dozen or so files that need merging, but I also don't know if there is some way that some svn client or tool can do this for me automatically.

Any suggestions on addressing this?

Comment: Please can you give details about the command line you ran. It may be due to the inversion of parameters...

Comment: When merging both TRUNK into branch and branch back into TRUNK, I used
svn merge https://full.path.to.svn/branchName .

Comment: What is A and B? Users?

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an answer, but as put in comments, you should really indicate which command line you wrote to perform your actions.

The command to merge branch into the trunk is `svn merge BRANCH TRUNK`.

Your problem may be due to the inversion of parameters in the command line: you may have done `svn merge TRUNK BRANCH`.

Comment: When merging both TRUNK into branch and branch back into TRUNK, I used
svn merge https://full.path.to.svn/branchName .

Our team does:
  * branch-> dev->test
  * merge TRUNK into branch-> run full test suite (this takes 1+ day(s))
  * merge branch back into TRUNK